# Checking if a value occurs once in a dictionary and where it occurs

Tags: python, dictionary

```
d = {0:0,1:0,2:0,3:1,4:0,5:0}
D = {0:False,1:False,2:False,3:True,4:False,5:False}
```

How would I be able to check if a value occurs **only** once in a dictionary and to see what key it happens. Such that the output would be like:

```
Value 1 occurs once at key 3
Value True occurs once at key 3
```

I have gone as far as to check how many times a value occurs using Counter.

```
print(Counter(d.values()))
Counter({True: 1, False: 5})
print(Counter(D.values()))
Counter({1: 1, 0: 5})
```

But am still unsure how to find which key it occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```py
from collections import Counter


def fn(d: dict):
    # a set of all unique values
    unique_values = {k for k, v in Counter(d.values()).items() if v == 1}

    for k, v in d.items():
        if v in unique_values:
            # You found your pair, do something with it
            print(f"Value {v} occurs once at key {k}")


d = {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 0, 5: 0}
D = {0: False, 1: False, 2: False, 3: True, 4: False, 5: False}
fn(d)
print("-----------------------------------")
fn(D)
```

output:

```
Value 1 occurs once at key 3
-----------------------------------
Value True occurs once at key 3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `defaultdict` to store all the keys that map to each value.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
revd = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in d.items():
    revd[v].append(k)
for k, v in revd.items():
    print(f'Value {k} occurs {len(v)} time(s) at key(s) {v}')
```

Comment: How would I write the last two lines in an if statement such that if that value exists once, do something.

Comment: @HudsonDing You can check `if len(v) == 1:` to test for only 1 occurrence.

Comment: Keep on getting returned with this error. `if k == 0 and len(v) == 1:
                  ^^^^^^
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()`

Comment: @HudsonDing You're probably iterating over the wrong dict. It should be in the second loop, not the first one. See demo: https://ideone.com/NEFNWB

Comment: I'm really not sure if it's my code or if I'm doing something wrong. I'll just send my code through, the code you gave me is located is lines 62-67. It seems to be returning two values, neither of the values which I want. https://pastebin.com/jX8gdHG , Also on how it works- don't worry about it, just spam thee number 3 until you get to `Player 1 is out!`, the expected result should be `Player [2] wins!` but I'm getting two lines of just `Player [0] wins!` and `Player [1] wins!`

Comment: What value do you want? It's hard to tell what you're doing there.

Comment: Value of 2, I edited the previous comment with some more info

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over that dict and validate each occurrence of `d.values()` using `Counter`. If a particular occurrence is `1` then `True`, otherwise `False`.

```py
from collections import Counter

d = {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 0, 5: 0}
# D = {0:False,1:False,2:False,3:True,4:False,5:False}

counter = dict(Counter(d.values()))
for key in d:
    result = True if counter[d[key]] == 1 else False
    if result:
        print(f'Value {d[key]} occurs once at key {key}')
        print(f'Value {result} occurs once at key {key}')
    d[key] = result
print(d)
```

The output will be:

```
Value 1 occurs once at key 3
Value True occurs once at key 3
{0: False, 1: False, 2: False, 3: True, 4: False, 5: False}
```

Comment: You don't need to convert `Counter` object to `dict` in order to get an item.

Comment: It's also inefficient because you are creating that Counter object for every single item in the dict.

Comment: Would this not work if there was multiple 1's

Comment: What is multiple 1's look like? Can you give me an example of input and output?